# What is the best way to root a 2012 Nexus 7 running 5.1.1 Lollipop?

Tags: rooting, nexus-7, 5.1-lollipop

I have had my N7 for about 5 or 6 months now, and I am considering rooting it. I would like to know the best one click rooting methods to use. I've heard of kingoroot, but I don't know if it roots 5.1.1 yet. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the Nexus Root Toolkit. It is the easiest method, and will walk you through all the steps (setting up drivers, etc.)

Here's a link: http://www.wugfresh.com/